# Filter the data from array of object based on condition using lodash

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I have the below Array of object set, I need to take the some of them based on the condition from the whole array set using lodash.

I have used _.filter(data, condition) in lodash, but expected result is not 
coming.

Anyone help me to resolve this ?

**Condition** : EarnCode < 90 && Hours === 0 (result will be skipped those data).

**Request Array set**:

```
[
  {
    "id" : 1,
    "EmpId" : 100,
    "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
    "SuperID" : 2000,
    "ReportNo" : "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
    "EarnCode" : 96,
    "Hours" : 0
  },
 {
    "id" : 3,
    "EmpId" : 100,
    "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
    "SuperID" : 2000,
    "ReportNo" : "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
    "EarnCode" : 96,
    "Hours" : 0
  },
  {
    "id" : 2,
    "EmpId" : 100,
    "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
    "SuperID" : 2000,
    "ReportNo" : "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
    "EarnCode" : 1,
    "Hours" : 0
  },
  {
    "id" : 5,
    "EmpId" : 100,
    "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
    "SuperID" : 2000,
    "ReportNo" : "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
    "EarnCode" : 1,
    "Hours" : 3
  }
]
```

**Expected Result:**

```
[
{
        "id" : 1,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
        "EarnCode" : 96,
        "Hours" : 0
      },
{
        "id" : 3,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
        "EarnCode" : 96,
        "Hours" : 0
      },
 {
        "id" : 5,
        "EmpId" : 100,
        "AcctCode" : "2001-00",
        "SuperID" : 2000,
        "ReportNo" : "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
        "EarnCode" : 1,
        "Hours" : 3
      }
]
```

Comment: Show us the code you tried out.

Comment: Unrelated, why do you want to add a library like lodash for doing this?

Comment: just reverse your condition and you will get what you want

Comment: Yeah, just reverse the condition (^^) to `EarnCode >= 90 || Hours !== 0`

Comment: Use lodash's `reject` instead of `filter` with your condition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just for completeness, following CRice's answer which is likely the way to go about this, if you insist that you must use lodash:

```js
const inputSet = [{
  "id": 1,
  "EmpId": 100,
  "AcctCode": "2001-00",
  "SuperID": 2000,
  "ReportNo": "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
  "EarnCode": 96,
  "Hours": 0
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "EmpId": 100,
  "AcctCode": "2001-00",
  "SuperID": 2000,
  "ReportNo": "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
  "EarnCode": 96,
  "Hours": 0
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "EmpId": 100,
  "AcctCode": "2001-00",
  "SuperID": 2000,
  "ReportNo": "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
  "EarnCode": 1,
  "Hours": 0
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "EmpId": 100,
  "AcctCode": "2001-00",
  "SuperID": 2000,
  "ReportNo": "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
  "EarnCode": 1,
  "Hours": 3
}]

// Negate your condition, filter keeps items where the condition is
// true, so for your example, you need either Hours to be non-zero
// OR for EarnCode to be greater than 90.
const resultSet = _.filter(inputSet, i => i.Hours !== 0 || i.EarnCode >= 90);
console.log(resultSet); // Includes items 1, 3, and 5.
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.5/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need to use lodash (if you don't want to), since the built in array `.filter` method will be enough to do this.

All you have to do is give it the right condition. In your case, that the item does not have 0 hours and an EarnCode less than 90. That condition can be represented as either:

`!(EarnCode < 90 && Hours === 0)`

or eqivalently:

`EarnCode >= 90 || Hours !== 0`

Using that second one, your filter might look like this:

```js
const inputSet = [{
  "id": 1,
  "EmpId": 100,
  "AcctCode": "2001-00",
  "SuperID": 2000,
  "ReportNo": "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
  "EarnCode": 96,
  "Hours": 0
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "EmpId": 100,
  "AcctCode": "2001-00",
  "SuperID": 2000,
  "ReportNo": "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
  "EarnCode": 96,
  "Hours": 0
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "EmpId": 100,
  "AcctCode": "2001-00",
  "SuperID": 2000,
  "ReportNo": "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
  "EarnCode": 1,
  "Hours": 0
}, {
  "id": 5,
  "EmpId": 100,
  "AcctCode": "2001-00",
  "SuperID": 2000,
  "ReportNo": "20180213.2015-06.2768.6",
  "EarnCode": 1,
  "Hours": 3
}]

// Negate your condition, filter keeps items where the condition is
// true, so for your example, you need either Hours to be non-zero
// OR for EarnCode to be greater than (or equal to) 90.
const resultSet = inputSet.filter(i => i.Hours !== 0 || i.EarnCode >= 90);
console.log(resultSet); // Includes items 1, 3, and 5.
```